# virtual methods, operator=(), operator<<();

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, objective-c++

```
class Port
{
private:
    char * brand;
    char style[20]; // i.e., tawny, ruby, vintage
    int bottles;
public:
    Port(const char * br = "none", const char * st = "none", int b = 0);
    Port(const Port & p); // copy constructor
    virtual ~Port() {delete[] brand; }
    Port & operator=(const Port & p);
    Port & operator+=(int b); // adds b to bottles
    Port & operator-=(int b); // subtracts b from bottles, if
    int BottleCount() const { return bottles; }
    virtual void Show() const;
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Port & p);
};



class VintagePort : public Port // style necessarily = "vintage"
{
private:
    char * nickname; // i.e., "The Noble" or "Old Velvet", etc.
    int year; // vintage year
public:
    VintagePort();
    VintagePort(const char * br, const char *st, int b, const char * nn, int y);
    VintagePort(const VintagePort & vp);
    ~VintagePort() { delete[]nickname;}
    VintagePort & operator=(const VintagePort & vp);
    virtual void Show() const;
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const VintagePort & vp);
};
```

I have to explain why `operator=()` and `operator<<()` are not
virtual. I think that `operator<<()` can't be virtual because only class methods could be, but I have no idea about operator=(). How does the pointer at basic class know which one of `operator=()` it has to use?

Second question is about how I can make `operator<<()` behave like a virtual method for example:

```
basicClass B;
inheritClass I;
basicClass *ptr;
ptr=&I;
std::cout << ptr // Here I'd like to use operator<<(std::ostream, inheritClass)
```

Comment: Re: `operator<<`. Yes, it can't be virtual because it's not a member. But commonly, you would implement it in terms of a virtual member, as in `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Port & p) { p.PrintMe(os); return os; }`. Here, `PrintMe` is a virtual method of base class that derived classes can override.

Comment: So the question is _"should I make `operator=` virtual?"_, right? Your intuition about `operator<<` is right, only methods can be `virtual`.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo yes, the question that i've got in my book is "Why operator=() isn't virtual?". You answered me about operator<<(), but what about operator=()? It is a method, isn't it? It could be virtual but it isn't. I have to answer why, but I have no idea.

Comment: Re: `operator=`. Note how the two flavors of `operator=` in your code have different signatures. It would be pointless to make `Port::operator=` virtual - `VintagePort::operator=`, as written, doesn't override it anyway. The whole notion of a polymorphic `operator=` doesn't usually make sense - what would it mean to assign an instance of `ModernPort` to `VintagePort`, say (assuming both classes derive from `Port`)?

Answer (score 1):

`operator =` is not virtual because it is not marked `virtual`. The declaration of `operator =` looks like this

```
//No virtual here
Port& operator =(const Port&);
```

If, however, `operator =` was virtual it would be declared like this

```
virtual Port& operator =(const Port&);
^^^^^^^ Virtual here!
```

Since `operator =` is not virtual the compiler uses static linkage when compiling. This means the function called is dependent on the type of the variable it is being referred to by. Consider this code:

```
VintagePort vp;

//Calls VintagePort::operator =(const VintagePort&)
vp = VintagePort();

Port* p = &vp;

//Calls Port::operator =(const Port&)
*p = Port();
```

`VintagePort::operator =` is called when it is being accessed as a `VintagePort`, however, `Port::operator =` is called when it is accessed as a `Port`. (Live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7837d617baa89e).)

---

To make `operator <<` behave as if it were virtual you would have to declare a virtual member function within your class that does the printing. Something like this

```
//Inside Port
virtual void Print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << brand << ' ' << style << ' ' << bottles;
}
```

Then in every class that derives from `Port` (like `VintagePort`) you would override the method to also print the values for that derived class. So for `VintagePort` you could do this

```
//Inside VintagePort
void Print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    //Make Port print first
    Port::Print(os);
    os << ' ' << nickname << ' ' << year;
}
```

Then in `operator <<` all you would have to do is to call the `Print` method on the argument. Which would look like this:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Port& p)
{
    P.Print();
    return os;
}
```

As a plus you don't have to overload `operator <<` for every derived the class as the overload only needs the virtual function in the `Port` class.

Answer (score 0):

This has the feeling of a [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is not what SO is for -- but anyways:

- Don't use character arrays. Use `std::string`:

  ```
  class Port
  {
  private:
       std::string brand;
       std::string style; // i.e., tawny, ruby, vintage
  //...
  };
  ```

  Moreover, and in general, don't use pointers where objects are appropriate. And if you need pointers, use smart pointers to clearly express the purpose.

  This is the *RAII* principle which underpins most of C++.
- If you follow the previous suggestion, there is no need to define: destructors, copy/move constructors, and -- that touches your question -- also not **assignment operators**. (And particularly, there is no need to overload the latter).
- `operator<<` can't should not declared `virtual`, as it is not a class member. It's a stand-alone function which, due to being a friend, may have access to private members of your port wine classes.

  But you can overload it outside of the class. This is what one straightforwardly does by setting up different overloads as `operator<<(ostream & os, const Port & p);` and `operator<<(ostream & os, const VintagePort & p);`.

Comment: I know that std::string is better than char array, but I'm learning from book and they used it for better explanation how does dynamic memory works in classes. Do you have any idea, why operator=() in this code isn't virtual?